# Closed form for $\int_1^\infty\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-y^2+4\,x^2y^2}}$

Tags: improper-integrals, gamma-function, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Consider the following integral:
$$\mathcal{I}=\int_1^\infty\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-y^2+4\,x^2y^2}}.$$
It can be represented as
$$\mathcal{I}=\int_1^\infty\frac{K(\sqrt{1-4\,x^2})}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\mathrm dx=\Re\int_0^1\frac{K\left(\sqrt\frac{1+3\,y^2}{1-y^2}\right)}{1-y^2}\mathrm dy,$$
where $K(x)$ is [the complete elliptic integral of the 1st kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html).

I was not able to further simplify any of these integrals, but numerical integration suggests the following conjectural closed form:
$$\mathcal{I}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{3\,\Gamma(1/3)^6}{2^{17/3}\pi^2}.$$
Can you suggest a proof of this conjecture?

---

Using [*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) I obtained a closed form for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of the [Meijer G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html):
$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{4}G_{3,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left|\begin{array}{c}1,\ \ 1,\ \ 1\\\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\\\end{array}\right.\right),$$
but I have no manual proof for that and do not know how to reduce it to $\frac{3\,\Gamma(1/3)^6}{2^{17/3}\pi^2}.$

Comment: How do you hunt a non-trivial integral with closed forms like this? Anyway, I love your integrals! (+1)

Comment: @sos440 I am experimenting a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edited** It turns out this integral is done in http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0891, which O.L. linked to in a comment to another question. This isn't much of an answer, really, as for all the closed forms I refer you to that paper.

Write the integral (by change of variable) as
$$ \frac12 \int_0^\infty K(\sqrt{-1-2\cosh \theta})\,d\theta, $$
then expand this into a double integral from the definition of $K$, and integrate over $\theta$ to get
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1+3t^2}} K\left( \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+3t^2}} \right). $$
Another change of variable
$$ t^2 = \frac{1}{v^2+1} $$
will bring it to the form
$$ \frac1\pi\overline V_3(1,1,1) = \int_0^\infty \frac{dv}{\sqrt{(v^2+4)(v^2+1)}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{v^2+4}}\right), $$
which is equation (32) in that paper. It is evaluated by considering an integral of a product of three modified Bessel functions, and that integral was done in two papers by W. N. Bailey in 1934 ("Some indefinite integrals involving Bessel functions"). As a consequence, the integral equals
$$ \Re\left( K(e^{-\pi i/6})^2\right). $$
In that paper, (equation 39) they also give the equivalent form (I don't know a proof why this is equivalent to the above)
$$ \frac12 K(\sin(\pi/12))K(\cos(\pi/12)) = \frac{\sqrt3}2 K(\sin(\pi/12))^2, $$
and the closed form exists because $\sin\frac\pi{12}$ is a singular value (see [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)) of the elliptic integral:
$$ \frac{3\Gamma(\frac13)^6}{32\pi^2 2^{2/3}}. $$

Comment: Actually, this question is positively settled by your another recent [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/405195/19661).

Comment: I did them in the wrong order.

Comment: Kirill, thank you for all your answers, they are amazing! I learn from them a lot.

Comment: I'm happy to help.