# Is $K\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}2\right)\stackrel?=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}{4\ \sqrt[4]3\ \sqrt\pi}$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, gamma-function, closed-form, conjectures

Working on [this conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404222/how-to-prove-int-0-infty-j-nux3dx-stackrel-frac-gamma1-6-gamma1-6), I found its corollary, which is also supported by numeric calculations up to at least $10^5$ decimal digits:
$$K\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}2\right)\stackrel?=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}{4\ \sqrt[4]3\ \sqrt\pi},$$
where $K(x)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the 1st kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html). I did not find this specific value at [*MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html), [*Wolfram Functions Site*](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/03/01/), [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Special_values) or [*DLMF*](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.6).

Is it a known value?

Comment: I'm always enjoying your integral calculations and conjectures! Again, a nice discovery! (+1)

Comment: Added some plain text to the title, the dropdown menus don't work otherwise.

Comment: Does the corresponding elliptic curve have CM?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html and also here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValuek3.html

Your value is actually
$$ \sin \frac\pi{12} = \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}{2}, $$
and according to MathWorld, it is known as the third singular value $k_3$. It satisfies
$$ K(\sqrt{1-k_3^2}) = \sqrt{3}K(k_3) $$
and
$$ K(k_3) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1/6)}{2\cdot 3^{3/4}\Gamma(2/3)}. $$
*Mathematica* says that the two closed forms are equal.