# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty J^3_0(x) e^{i\omega x}\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Hi I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$
\mathcal{I}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty J^3_0(x) e^{i\omega x}\mathrm dx
$$
analytically.  We can also write
$$
\mathcal{I}(\omega)=\mathcal{FT}\big(J^3_0(x)\big)
$$ which is the Fourier Transform of the cube of Bessel function.  The Bessel function $J_0$ is given by
$$
J_0(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ix\sin t} \mathrm dt.
$$
If it helps, we can represent the cube of the Bessel function by
$$
J^3_0(x)=-3\int J^2_0(x) J_1(x) \mathrm dx, \ \ \ \ \ J_1(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(t-x\sin t)} \mathrm dt.
$$
In general
$$
J_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(nt-x\sin t)}\mathrm  dt.
$$
The Fourier Transforms of the Bessel function and its square is given by
$$
\mathcal{FT}\big(J_0(x)\big)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1)}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}
$$ 
and 
$$
\mathcal{FT}\big(J^2_0(x)\big)=\frac{\sqrt{2}K\big(1-\frac{\omega^2}{4}\big)\big(\theta(-\omega-2)-1\big)\big(\theta(\omega-2)-1\big)}{\pi^{3/2}}         
$$
where K is the elliptic-K function and $\theta$ is the heaviside step function.  However I need the cube...

Comment: @Jeff This is a very interesting question! I tried to find an answer to it some time ago, but failed. For a specific case $\omega=0$ (also not trivial) you may take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404222/how-to-prove-int-0-infty-j-nux3dx-stackrel-frac-gamma1-6-gamma1-6

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Well if you have failed, then I guess there is no closed form! This calculation came up in a physics problem so I figured there must be a closed form ;)!  Thanks!

Comment: Is this not a context in which the Convolution Theorem would be useful?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out that the Fourier transform of $J_0^3$ can still be expressed
in terms of complete elliptic integrals, but it's considerably
more complicated than the formula for ${\cal FT}(J_0^2)$:
for starters, it involves the periods of a curve $E$ defined over ${\bf C}$
but (except for a few special values of $\omega$) not over ${\bf R}$.

Assume $|\omega| < 3$, else $I(\omega) = 0$.  Then the relevant curve is
$$
E : Y^2 = X^3
   - \bigl(\frac{3}{4} f^2 + \frac{27}{2} f - \frac{81}{4}\bigr) X^2
   + 9 f^3 X
$$
where
$$
f = \frac12 \bigl( e + 1 + \sqrt{e^2-34e+1} \bigr)
$$
and
$$
e = \bigl( |\omega| + \sqrt{\omega^2-1} \, \bigr)^2.
$$
Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be generators of the period lattice of $E$
with respect to the differential $dx/y$ (note that these are twice
the periods that **gp** reports, because **gp** integrates $dx/2y$
for reasons coming from the arithmetic of elliptic curves).  Then:
if $|\omega| \leq 1$ then
$$
I(\omega) =
  \left|\,f\,\right|^{5/2}\, \left|\,f-1\right| \frac{\Delta}{(2\pi)^2},
$$
where $\Delta = \bigl|{\rm Im} (\lambda_1 \overline{\lambda_2}) \bigr|$
is the area of the period lattice of $E$.  If $1 \leq |\omega| \leq 3$ then
$$
I(\omega) = \left|\,f\,\right|^{-4}\, \left|\,f-1\right|^5 (3/2)^{13/2}
 \frac{\Delta'}{(2\pi)^2},
$$
where $\Delta' = \bigl| {\rm Re}(\lambda_1 \overline{\lambda_2}) \bigr|$
for an appropriate choice of generators $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$
(these "appropriate" generators satisfy $|\lambda_1|^2 = \frac32 |\lambda_2|^2$,
which determines them uniquely up to $\pm$ except for finitely many
choices of $\omega$).

The proof, alas, is too long to reproduce here, but here's the basic idea.
The Fourier transform of $J_0$ is $(1-\omega^2)^{-1/2}$ for $|\omega|<1$
and zero else.  Hence the Fourier transforms of $J_0^2$ and $J_0^3$
are the convolution square and cube of $(1-\omega^2)^{-1/2}$.
For $J_0^2$, this convolution square is supported on $|\omega| \leq 2$,
and in this range equals
$$
\int_{t=|\omega|-1}^1 \left( (1-t^2) (1-(|\omega|-t)^2) \right)^{-1/2} \, dt,
$$
which is a period of an elliptic curve [namely the curve
$u^2 = (1-t^2) (1-(|\omega|-t)^2)$], a.k.a. a complete eliptic integral.
For $J_0^3$, we likewise get a two-dimensional integral, over a hexagon
for $|\omega|<1$ and a triangle for $1 \leq |\omega| < 3$, that is
a period of the K3 surface
$$
u^2 = (1-s^2) (1-t^2) (1-(|\omega|-s-t)^2).
$$
(The phase change at $|\omega|=1$ was already noted here in a
now-deleted partial answer.)
In general, periods of K3 surfaces are hard to compute, but this one
turns out to have enough structure that we can convert the period
into a period of the surface $E \times \overline E$ where $\overline E$
is the complex conjugate.

Now to be honest I have only the formulas for the "correspondence" between
our K3 surface and $E \times \overline E$, which was hard enough to do,
but didn't keep track of the elementary multiplying factor
that I claim to be $\left|\,f\,\right|^{5/2}\, \left|\,f-1\right|$
or $\left|\,f\,\right|^{-4}\, \left|\,f-1\right|^5 (3/2)^{13/2}$.
I obtained these factors by comparing numerical values for the few
choices of $\omega$ for which I was able to compute $I(\omega)$
to high precision (basically rational numbers with an even numerator
or denominator); for example $I(2/5)$ can be computed in **gp**
in under a minute as

```
intnum(x=0,5*Pi,2*cos(2*x/5) * sumalt(n=0,besselj(0,x+5*n*Pi)^3))
```

There were enough such $c$, and the formulas are sufficiently simple,
that they're virtually certain to be correct.

Here's **gp** code to get $e$, $f$, $E$, and generators $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$
of the period lattice:

```
e = (omega+sqrt(omega^2-1))^2
f = (sqrt(e^2-34*e+1)+(e+1)) / 2
E = ellinit( [0, -3/4*f^2-27/2*f+81/4, 0, 9*f^3, 0] )
L = 2*ellperiods(E)
lambda1 = L[1]
lambda2 = L[2]
```

NB the last line requires use of **gp** version 2.6.x; earlier versions
did not directly implement periods of curves over $\bf C$.

For $\omega=0$ we have $e=1$, $f=3$, and $E$ is the curve
$Y^2 = X^3 - 27 X^2 + 243 X = (X-9)^3 + 3^6$,
so the periods can be expressed in terms of beta functions and
we recover the case $\nu=0$ of Question 404222, [How to prove $\int_0^\infty J_\nu(x)^3dx\stackrel?=\frac{\Gamma(1/6)\ \Gamma(1/6+\nu/2)}{2^{5/3}\ 3^{1/2}\ \pi^{3/2}\ \Gamma(5/6+\nu/2)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404222) .

Comment: This seems nice, but doesn't quite help me as I don't understand anything.  How did you come up with your curve, what is GP?  What two dimensional integral do you get for $J^3_0$?  Perhaps you can put the integral I am trying to calculate, and what is equal to in terms of elliptic functions.  Your proof is very deep, and above my head.  I shall award you the bounty if you can clear these things up for me, and also explain it a bit simpler (if possible). Thanks

Comment: I can try to answer some of these questions: 
The two-dimensional integral is
$$
(2\pi)^{-2} 
\iint ds \, dt \bigg/ \left( (1-s^2) (1-t^2) (1-(\omega-s-t)^2) \right)^{1/2}
$$
over the region where $|s|<1$, $|t|<1$ and $|\omega-s-t|<1$.
**gp** is a computer algebra system, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP .
The **gp** code together with the formulas let you compute $I(\omega)$
for any $\omega$.  Yes, the periods of $E$ can be expressed as multiples of the
elliptic functions ${\bf K}(k)$, ${\bf K}'(k)$ for some complex $k$,
but these formulas are even more complicated because [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] to put $E$ in the form $y^2 = (1-x^2) (1-k^2 x^2)$ you need to solve
a quartic for $k$, and thus to extract two more square roots.
Finally, the path from the K3 surface
$$ u^2 =  (1-s^2) (1-t^2) (1-(\omega-s-t)^2) $$
to $E \times \overline{E}$ is a sequence of three rational
changes of variable whose existence is predicted by the general
theory of K3 surfaces (which also says that here $E$ and $\overline{E}$
are $6$-isogenous) but I had to work out explicitly.  I don't know
how much more I can explain here; in any case I doubt that the formula for
$I(\omega)$ can be made much simpler.

Comment: Ok, so are you stating this:
$$
\mathcal{I}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty J^3_0(x) e^{i\omega x}dx=(2\pi)^{-2}  \iint ds \, dt  \left( (1-s^2) (1-t^2) (1-(\omega-s-t)^2) \right)^{-1/2}?
$$
Thanks.  I am not sure what the large / means in your double integral that you posted in the comment.  Is that a division sign?  what is it?  Thanks again.  I think this problem is too advanced for me now that I am seeing the solution, although I will still award the bounty to you.  Great.

Comment: Yes, your formula is equivalent to what I wrote:
the big / is a division sign as you guessed, and is needed
because the Fourier transform of $J_0$ itself is $1/\sqrt{1-\omega^2}$,
not $\sqrt{1-\omega^2}$; your use of the exponent $-1/2$ has the same effect.
Thank you not just for the bounty but also for calling my attention to 
the Fourier-transform problem: I hadn't thought to look for K3 periods 
in this context.  I should at least be able to post some more details
of the numerical example of $\omega = 2/5$, and also to show how the
calculation works for some $\omega\in(1,3)$ such as $4/3$.

Comment: You can post as much more as you want, it would greatly help me out.  However, you have already earned the Bounty.  So thanks a lot.  I may have some more questions, I just need to try go through these details, it is not so clear to me.  I shall post some more interesting Fourier transform problems than!  This problem arised in the 1980's at Sofia University, although me and my college friends at the time couldn't find a closed form.  This is the best I have seen.

Comment: Prof. Elkies would you see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760451/evaluate-displaystyle-lim-j-to0-lim-k-to-infty-frackjj-ek), please? I really hope you can answer it for me. Thank you. (-^〇^-)

Comment: Hello Prof. Elkies. Could you point a reference for the computation of period? Also, does this generalize to Fourier transform of $J_0(ax) J_0(x)^2$? I am asking this because this can also be expressed as products of two $K$'s. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Actually more is true: the Fourier transform of $J_0(ax)J_0(x)^2$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ can be expressed in elliptic integral $K(m) = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-mt^2)}}$.

Here is the explicit form of the already nontrivial case $a=1$: let $$\tag{1}G(w) = \frac{2 \sqrt{4-3 t}}{\pi ^2 w(1-t)}K(m_+)K(m_-)$$
with $$2v = 5-w^2+\sqrt{(w^2-9)(w^2-1)} \qquad t=\frac{v}{v-1}$$
$$4m_{\pm} = 2\pm v\sqrt{4-v} -(2-v)\sqrt{1-v}$$
then for $s\in \mathbb{R}$, our Fourier transform is $$\color{royalblue}{\int_0^\infty  J_0(t)^3 \cos(ts) dt} = -\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\Im[G(s+i\varepsilon)] $$

One has to be careful about branch problem though, see the end. Special cases:
$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^\infty J_0(x)^3 \cos x dx &= \frac{(2-\sqrt{2}) (\sqrt{2}+1)}{16 \pi ^3}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^2 \\
\int_0^\infty J_0(x)^3 \cos(\sqrt{5}x)dx &= \frac{1}{4\pi^3} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{20}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{20}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{9}{20}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{21}{20}\right) \end{aligned}$$

---

Forget our notation of $G$ above, let
$$G(w) = \frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_{[0,\pi]^3} \frac{dx_1dx_2dx_3}{w-\cos x_1-\cos x_2 - \cos x_3}$$
then $G(w)$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}-[-3,3]$. Using $\int_0^\pi e^{t\cos x} dx = \pi I_0(t)$ we have
$$G(w) = \frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_{[0,\pi]^3} \int_0^\infty e^{-t(w-\cos x_1-\cos x_2 - \cos x_3)} dx_i dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-tw} I_0(t)^3 dt$$
here we assume $w > 3$ to ensure convergence. By deforming contour, we can switch the path  of integral to be $\int_0^{i\infty}$ (integral over big circular arc $\to 0$ when $w>3$), so $$G(w) = i\int_0^\infty e^{-itw} J_0(t)^3 dt = -i\int_0^\infty e^{itw} J_0(t)^3 dt$$
Now RHS is analytic on $\Im w > 0$, so analytic continuation gives
$$G(w) = -i\int_0^\infty e^{itw} J_0(t)^3 dt \qquad \Im w > 0$$
In particular, we see for $s\in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}G(s+i\varepsilon)$ exists, denote it by $G_{\Re}(s) - iG_{\Im}(s)$. Then above equality gives
$$G_{\Re}(s) = \int_0^\infty \sin(ts)J_0(t)^3 dt \qquad G_{\Im}(s) = \color{royalblue}{\int_0^\infty \cos(ts)J_0(t)^3 dt}$$
thus it suffices to show the triple integral actually equals RHS of $(1)$. The integral of $G_{\Re}(s)$ is not our goal, but we see it can be expressed as elliptic integral too.

---

The $G(w)$ is called *[Watson triple integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WatsonsTripleIntegrals.html) of simple cubic lattice*. It turns out that the more general
$$G(w,a) = \frac{1}{\pi^3}\int_{[0,\pi]^3} \frac{dx_1dx_2dx_3}{w-a\cos x_1-\cos x_2 - \cos x_3}$$
called *Watson triple integral of singly anisotropic cubic lattice* can also be expressed in terms of $K$. Its closed-form evaluation is a culmination of ingenious symbolic computation, which will be only briefly recapitulated below, the reader are strongly encouraged to read the reference for this spectacular achievement.

[to be added later....]

---

$(1)$ holds at least for $w>3$ when principal branch of square root and $K$ is taken. Since $G(w)$ has no branch point on $\Im w > 0$ from the triple integral definition, $(1)$ is true for all $w \in \mathbb{C}-[-3,3]$ after analytic continuation.

For our concerned range $0<\Re w < 3, \Im w >0$, I think the only term that can cause deviation from principal branch is the term $\sqrt{(w^2-9)(w^2-1)}$ in $v$. After this has been considered, the following Mathematica code can calculate $G(w)$ in our range ($\Im w = 0$ not included)

```
G[w_] := Module[{x, y, v, t, m1, m2}, x = Re[w]; y = Im[w]; 
   If[5 x - x^3 + x*y^2 <= 0, 
    v = 1/2 (5 - w^2 + Sqrt[(w^2 - 9) (w^2 - 1)]), 
    v = 1/2 (5 - w^2 - Sqrt[(w^2 - 9) (w^2 - 1)])]; t = v/(v - 1); 
   m1 = 1/2 (1 + v*Sqrt[4 - v]/2 - (2 - v) Sqrt[1 - v]/2); 
   m2 = 1/2 (1 - v*Sqrt[4 - v]/2 - (2 - v) Sqrt[1 - v]/2); 
   2/Pi^2/w*Sqrt[4 - 3 t]/(1 - t)*EllipticK[m1] EllipticK[m2]];
```