# Bessel function integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}x^{m}\left(J_{0}(bx) \right)^{2} \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am  working on a  problem. Solving the PDE for my problem, these Bessel integrals arise:

$$\int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}x^m(J_0(bx))^2dx,\quad \int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}x^m(J_1(bx))^2dx\qquad \text{and} \qquad\int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}x^mJ_0(bx)J_1(bx)dx$$

where $~J_0~$ and $~J_1~$ are the Bessel functions of first kind.

I haven't found the solution in any table or book, and due to my limited background in applied mathematics I don't know how to integrate it by myself.

Does anybody know the solution?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I m working on it until to prove them.

Comment: See 2.12.38.4 of Prudnikov, et al., vol 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not a clear answer. But I myself is in the process of following the derivations of some of the well known integrals involving Bessel functions, and you may find your answers in Luke's, "*Integrals of Bessel Functions*", p.314 and after. The pity is that you can't find in detail how they are derived. Maybe you should consult the original papers if you are interested in the derivations. It seems to me that the multiplications of the Bessel functions sre transformed to the single one by the additional theorem, which then is followed by transforming into elliptic integrals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: F.Y.I., you may also find some in P. F. Byrds and M. D. Friedman, "Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists". If I have time, I might upload how the derivations can be obtained in the future, but I'm not sure I have time to do it. The clue is written in G. N. Watson's masterpiece "The Theory of Bessel Functions"

Comment: Since I cannot access Luke's book, could you tell me if these integrals can be further reduced or simplified ? Thanks.

Comment: Dr. Claude Leibovici: Upon your request, I have sent an email(one with my name tag on) with the pdf attached to your email address. If it doesn't reach you, please let me know.

Comment: Dr. Claude Leibovici: As you can see in my email that was sent to you, the one with the edited answer written above in your column is the same as that in Luke's book.

Answer (score 1):

I have no access to Luke's book *"Integrals of Bessel Functions"* that 萬雄彦 recommended in his/her answer.

Using a CAS, I got some results. Naming
$$I_{i,j}=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-ax}\, x^m\, J_i(bx)\, J_j(bx)\,dx$$
$$\color{blue}{I_{0,0}=a^{-(m+1)} \Gamma (m+1) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+2}{2};1,1;-\frac{4b^2}{a^2}\right)}$$ provided
$b\geq 0\land \Re(m)+1>0\land ((\Re(a)=0\land \Re(m)<1)\lor \Re(a)>0)$
$$\color{blue}{I_{1,1}=\frac{b^2}{4}  a^{-(m+3)} \Gamma (m+3) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{m+3}{2},\frac{m+4}{2};2,3;-\frac{4b^2}{a^2}\right)}$$ provided
$b\geq 0\land \Re(m)+1>0\land ((\Re(a)=0\land \Re(m)<1)\lor \Re(a)>0)$
$$\color{blue}{I_{0,1}=\frac{b}{2} a^{-(m+2)} \Gamma (m+2) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m+3}{2};2,2;-\frac{4b^2}{a^2}\right)}$$
provided
$b\geq 0\land \Re(m)+2>0\land ((\Re(a)=0\land \Re(m)<1)\lor \Re(a)>0)$

A few numerical checks have been done.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general, it seems that 
$$J_{i,j}= \frac{ 2^{(i+j)}\, \Gamma (i+1)\, \Gamma (j+1) \, a^{(m+i+j+1)}}{\Gamma (m+i+j+1)\, b^{(i+j)}} \, I_{i,j}$$ can write
$$\color{blue}{J_{i,j}=\,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{i+j+1}{2},\frac{i+j+2}{2},\frac{m+i+j+1
   }{2},\frac{m+i+j+2}{2};i
   +1,j+1,i+j+1;-\frac{4 b^2}{a^2}\right)}$$
provided $\Re(m+i+j)>-1\land b\geq 0\land ((\Re(a)=0\land \Re(m)<1)\lor \Re(a)>0)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I hate to be that person, but isn't this site supposed to be devoted to understanding the things that Mathematica/Maple churns out, instead of just citing them? Wouldn't a proof be necessary for this to be an acceptable and accept-worthy answer?

Comment: @ DinosaurEgg. I'm about to establish the formulas given by Claude Leibovici. It is not finished yet.

Comment: @RyoKen. When finished, please, add an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici , of course.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, spot on! If here’s not about understanding, it’s not worth much. Kudos, +100.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652131/16033), we can use a generalization of [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) called the [*method of brackets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem#Bracket_integration_method) to derive some of the results in **Claude Leibovici**'s answer.

---

Assume that $b \ge0 $,  $a >2b$, and $m \in \mathbb{Z} >-1$.

The exponential function has the series representation $$e^{- ax} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!}(ax)^{j} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \phi{_j}(ax)^{j}. $$

And the square of the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero has the [series representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/06/01/04/02/01/0004/) $$J_{0}(bx)^{2} = {_2F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2};1,1;-(bz)^{2} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k} \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \,  (bx)^{2k}.$$

Therefore, the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax} x^{m} J_{0}(bx)^{2} \, \mathrm dx$ has the corresponding bracket series $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{j,k} \, a^{j} \, b^{2k}  \, \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \,  \langle j+2k+m+1 \rangle.$$

Since there are $2$ indices but only $1$ bracket, there are two cases to examine.

If we let $k$ be a free parameter, then the bracket vanishes if $j=-2k-m-1$, and we have the contribution $$\begin{align} S_{1} &=  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} a^{-2k-m-1} \, b^{2k} \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, \Gamma \left( 
2k+m+1 \right) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} a^{-(m+1)} \, \left( -\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right)^{k}  \,  \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, \frac{2^{2k+m}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \, \Gamma \left(k+ \frac{m}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(k+ \frac{m}{2}+1 \right) \\ &= a^{-(m+1)} \, \frac{2^{m}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{m}{2}+1 \right) \,  {_3F_2} \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{m+1}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; 1,1; -\frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right) \\ &= a^{-(m+1)} \, 2^{m} \, \Gamma \left(2 \left(\frac{m}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) 2^{-2(m/2+1/2)+1} \,  {_3F_2} \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{m+1}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; 1,1; -\frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right) \\ &= a^{-(m+1)} \, \Gamma(m+1)  \,  {_3F_2} \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{m+1}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; 1,1; -\frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right). \end{align}$$

On the second and fourth lines I used [Legendre's duplication formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html).

If we let $j$ be a free parameter, then the bracket vanishes if $k=- \frac{j}{2} - \frac{m}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$, and we have the contribution $$ S_{2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!} \, a^{j} \, b^{-j-m-1} \, \frac{\color{red}{\Gamma \left(- \frac{j+m}{2} \right)}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(\frac{-j-m+1}{2} \right)^{2}} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{j+m+1}{2} \right). $$

Since not all terms of this series are finite, we discard it.

Therefore, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax} x^{m} J_{0}(bx)^{2} \, \mathrm dx = S_{1} =  \Gamma(m+1) \, a^{-(m+1)}\,  {_3F_2} \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{m+1}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; 1,1; -\frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right)$$ for $b \ge 0$, $a>2b$, and $m \in \mathbb{Z} >-1$.

---

Now assume that $b \ge 0$, $a>2b$, and $m \in \mathbb{Z} > -2$.

The product $J_{0}(bx) J_{1}(bx)$ has the [series representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.12.E1) $$ \begin{align} J_{0}(bx)J_{1}(bx) &= \frac{bx}{2} \, {_2F_3} \left( \frac{3}{2}, 1; 1, 2, 2; (bx)^{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{bx}{2} \, {_1F_2} \left( \frac{3}{2}; 2, 2; (bx)^{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{bx}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k} \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(k+2 \right)^{2}} (bx)^{2k}. \end{align}$$

Therefore, the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} x^{m} J_{0}(bx)J_{1}(bx) \, \mathrm dx$ has the corresponding bracket series $$ \frac{b}{2} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{j,k} \, a^{j} \, b^{2k}  \, \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+2)^{2}} \,  \langle j+2k+m+2 \rangle.$$

There are again two cases to examine.

If we let $j$ be a free parameter, then the bracket vanishes if $ j= -2k-m-2$, and we have the contribution $$ \begin{align} S_{3} &= \frac{b}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \,  a^{-2k-m-2} \, b^{2k}  \, \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+2)^{2}} \Gamma \left(2k+m+2 \right) \\ &= \small \frac{b}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} a^{-(m+2)} \left(-\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right)^{k} \, \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+2)^{2}} \frac{2^{2k+m+1}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \, \Gamma \left(k+ \frac{m}{2} + 1\right) \Gamma \left(k+ \frac{m}{2}+\frac{3}{2} \right) \\ &=  \frac{b}{2} \frac{a^{-(m+2)} 2^{m+1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}  \, \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1 \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \right) {_3F_2} \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; \frac{m+3}{2};2,2; - \frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right) \\ &=  \frac{b}{2} \, \frac{a^{-(m+2)} 2^{m+1}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) 2^{-m-1} \,  \Gamma(m+2) \, {_3F_2} \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; \frac{m+3}{2};2,2; - \frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right) \\ &= \frac{b}{2} \, a^{-(m+2)} \, \Gamma(m+2) \, {_3F_2} \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}; \frac{m+3}{2};2,2; - \frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right). \end{align}$$

If we let $k$ be a free parameter, we get a series like before that doesn't have all finite terms.

Therefore, we have $$\small \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} x^{m} J_{0}(bx) J_{1}(bx) \, \mathrm dx = S_{3} =  \frac{b}{2} \, a^{-(m+2)} \, \Gamma(m+2) \, {_3F_2} \left(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{m+2}{2}, \frac{m+3}{2};2,2; - \frac{4b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right)$$ for $b \ge 0$, $a > 2b$, and  $m \in \mathbb{Z} > -2$.

---

Since the Laplace transform defines an analytic function in the half-plane that it converges absolutely, analytic continuation extends both results to $\Re(a) >0$.

Comment: Nice solution and approach and $+1$

Answer (score 1):

The product of Bessel functions is expressible as a hypergeometric series:

$$J_{v}(x)J_{\mu}(x) = \frac{\left({\frac{x}{2}}\right)^{v+\mu}}{\Gamma(1+v)\Gamma(1+\mu)}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1+v+\mu}{2}\right)_{j}\left(1+\frac{v+\mu}{2}\right)_{j}(-x^2)^j}{(1)_{j}(1+v)_{j}(1+\mu)_{j}(1+v+\mu)_{j}}$$

So if $v=\mu=0$

$$J_{0}^2(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}(-x^2)^j}{(1)_{j}(1)_{j}(1)_{j}}$$

Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}J_{0}^2(bx)dx =& \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}(-b^2x^2)^j}{(1)_{j}(1)_{j}(1)_{j}}dx\\
=& \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}(-1)^jb^{2j}}{(1)_{j}(1)_{j}(1)_{j}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xa}x^{2j} dx\\
=& \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}(-1)^jb^{2j}}{(1)_{j}(1)_{j}(1)_{j}}\frac{1}{a^{2j+1}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-w}w^{2j} dw\\
=& \frac{1}{a}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}\Gamma(2j+1)(-1)^j}{(1)_{j}(1)_{j}} \frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2j} }{j!}\\
=&  \frac{1}{a} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{j}}{(1)_{j}} \frac{\left(-\frac{4b^2}{a^2}\right)^{j} }{j!}\\
=& \frac{1}{a}{}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;-\frac{4b^2}{a^2}\right)
\end{align*}

Recalll that

$$K(p) = \frac{\pi}{2} {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;p^2\right)$$

where $K(p)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind with modulus $p$.

So

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}J_{0}^2(bx)dx = \frac{2}{a\pi}K\left(i\frac{2b}{a}\right)$$

since $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and if $b\in \mathbb{R}$ this modulus is purely imagnary and we can make the transformation

$$K(ip) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}K\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)$$
So

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}J_{0}^2(bx)dx = \frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}K\left(\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}\right)$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $a$ $m$ times

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^mx^me^{-ax}J_{0}^2(bx)dx = \frac{d^m}{da^m} \left[\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}K\left(\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}\right)\right]$$

Then

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^me^{-ax}J_{0}^2(bx)dx = (-1)^m\frac{d^m}{da^m} \left[\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}K\left(\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}}\right)\right]}$$

However, this is not an easy to calculate derivative and the complexity compounded fast.

We can do a similar process for the case $v=\mu=1$. See entry 6.612 in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, *Table of integrals, series, and products, 7th edition.*